# Mailto links are not working for RTL(arabic) in Android

Tags: android, markdown

Mailto links are not working(means it is not clickable and highlighted) for RTL(arabic) in Android. Both, Anchor of Link and Mailto are getting visible on screen and both are non-clickable. Ideally only, anchor of link should be visible on screen.

strings.xml (Arabic)

```
<string name="contact_support_text_linked">اإذا كانت لديك أية أسئلة أو استفسارات يرجى التواصل مع [support@gmail.com]  (mailto:support@gmail.com).</string>
```

In LTR language(like English), it is working properly. As expected, only anchor of link is visible on screen and it is clickable.

strings.xml (English)

```
<string name="contact_support_text_linked">Contact [support@gmail.com](mailto:support@gmail.com) if you have any questions or concerns.</string>
```

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the whitespace between `[support@gmail.com]` and `(mailto:support@gmail.com)`?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderHoffmann, thanks man, it works perfectly. Actually strings.xml for Arabic is generated by Lokalise SDK. Again thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As @AlexanderHoffmann said in the comment, remove the whitespace between [support@gmail.com] and (mailto:support@gmail.com) works perfectly.